# Is there any PC software that I can use to help edit Roland RD700NX sets/perform maintenance?

Tags: maintenance, keyboard

I've just downloaded the V2 software for my RD 700NX and see the RD-NX Editor seems to only work on the iPad. I've searched and can't find anything, but does anyone know of any way to edit my keyboard's settings from a PC.

I'd love to be able to perform maintenance in this app too - backup settings etc, as my 2 year old is very very quick at hitting the write button! (I think she likes the flashing lights!)

Answer (score 2):

If you've already searched the roland site and hit google with RD700NX and found nothing,
then you may need to fall back on a more "general purpose" sysex librarian software.  I've never messed with such stuff.  It will probably not let you edit parameters of the synth.  But at least it could save and restore sysex dumps that the synth is capable of.
good luck to ya.

Comment: Appreciate the reply Stephen. I'll leave the question as unanswered hoping someone is able to suggest something that can do editing of the keyboard too. So frustrating that there's that iPad app but nothing for a PC.